# Understanding how the CDF is derived?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I referred one of the research paper and found the expression of CDF. I am not getting how that CDF expression is derived. The different steps involved in the derivation are given below-

$I = \text{Pr}\Bigl(\alpha = 0\Bigr)$ ----(1)

where $\text{Pr}$ is the probability. $\alpha $ is given by $\alpha = \text{max}\Bigl(1-\frac{\phi}{P_s|f|^2},0\Bigr)$ where $|f|^2$ is exponential random variable and $P_s$ is signal to noise ratio (SNR), $\phi$ is a constant.

Finally, the equation (1) is derived as $I = \text{Pr}\Bigl(|f|^2<\frac{\phi}{P_s}\Bigr) = 1-\exp\Bigl(-\frac{-\phi}{\lambda P_s}\Bigr)$ ----(2)

I am not getting how the "=" sign in equation (2) changed to "<".

Any help in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that:
$$\alpha = 0 \iff 1 - \frac{\phi}{P_s|f|^2} \le 0$$

From this it follows:
$$\mathbb P(\alpha=0) = \mathbb P \left(1 - \frac{\phi}{P_s|f|^2} \le 0\right) = \mathbb P \left(|f|^2 \le \frac{\phi}{P_s}\right)$$
You said in your question that $|f^2|$ is exponential, lets say with rate $1/\lambda$, then:
$$\mathbb P \left(|f|^2 \le \frac{\phi}{P_s}\right) = 1-\exp\left(-\frac{\phi}{\lambda P_s}\right)$$

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer sir....how " = " sign is changed to less than or equal to sign....

Comment: According to your definition $\alpha = \text{max}\Bigl(1-\frac{\phi}{P_s|f|^2},0\Bigr)$. When is $\alpha=0$ then?

Comment: Ok...will go through your hint sir....

Comment: I am trying to understand your hint.... I know its related to IFF (if and only if) symbol in maths.....but not getting it clearly .... can you please elaborate further....

Comment: I got your Hint....Thank you so much sir....But in your case the less than or equal to symbol is present while in Eq.(2)  only less than symbol is used......So which one is correct.....

Comment: It doesn't matter in case of a continous random variable, since $\mathbb P(|f|^2=x) = 0 (\forall x\in\mathbb R)$. However, the equality should be included if you want to be accurate.

Comment: Thank you so much sir....